# Exemplo simples autenticação com nível sem hibernate e spring

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc

Gostaria de um exemplo simples de autenticação de usuário.

Já tenho a tabela no banco de dados, que contém os dados do usuário e o nível (Administrador, usuário comum).

Como estou sem tempo para mexer com Hibernate e Spring, quero saber se tenho que colocar um método (Estou  utilizando o padrão DAO) que faz consulta no banco de dados selecionando nome de usuário e senha e se tenho que criar uma ManagedBean especial para a parte de autenticação.

Tenho que criar um arquivo `.xhtml` para a página de login.

Answer (score 2):

O modo mais simples mesmo é com Filter. Com o filter, que já é do java, você consegue interceptar o request e validar se determinado usuário está ativo ou não.

Com o filter você pode determinar qual a qual pasta/arquivo o usuário pode ter acesso logado ou não.

Aqui tem um exemplo: http://uaihebert.com/?p=1414

Assim você poderia configurar um filter no web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AdminPagesFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.AdminPagesFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AdminPagesFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/protected/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

E um filter poderia ser declarado como:

```
public class AdminPagesFilter extends AbstractFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        User user = (User) req.getSession(true).getAttribute("user");

        if (!user.isAdmin()) {
            accessDenied(request, response, req);
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pela praticidade, recomendo que você utilize o spring-security. Ele controla pra você o acesso às páginas que você definir e ainda possui um mecanismo de Roles, que te permite ter diferentes níveis de acesso.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de login básico:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

Comment: Adicione mais conteúdo na sua resposta. Normalmente respostas contendo apenas links não são muito bem vistas, afinal, se o site sair do ar a resposta se torna inútil, além de estar em outra língua.